# С какой буквы пишутся слова «церковь, храм, собор»?

Tags: прописная, или, строчная

Интересно,  как ТЕПЕРЬ пишутся слова «церковь, храм, собор», стоящие  перед названием. Они вроде бы считались приложениями и писались со строчной буквы, то есть не включались в имя собственное, например: «Князь Андрей Боголюбский построил храм Покрова на Нерли». А  теперь можно встретить разнообразные варианты, что не есть хорошо.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.

Я, собственно, хотела предложить вариант для одной из текущих тем в виде "храм Богини Море", но решила предварительно проверить, как там с храмом - всё ли в порядке. Оказалось, что всё в беспорядке. Например, Храм Рождества Христова, официальный сайт, написание с прописной буквы. И во многих других случаях также используется прописная буква. А как там у Лопатина, что слышно?

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я знаю, слово "Церковь" пишется с большой буквы, когда идет речь о Церкви как институте, а когда речь о здании храма, то с маленькой.